# How to make one array from three arrays having common fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to create a HTML view for which I need a specific pattern of the array.I have three arrays like this:

1st:

```
 classes = [
    { classid: 1, classname: "class 1" },
    { classid: 2, classname: "class 2" },
    { classid: 3, classname: "class 3" },
    { classid: 4, classname: "class 4" },
    { classid: 5, classname: "class 5" },
  ];
```

2nd:

```
 classwithSubjectIDSubjectName = [
        { classid: 1, subjectid: 10, subjectname: "Hindi" },
        { classid: 1, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" },
        { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" },
        { classid:3, subjectid: 12, subjectname: "GEO" },
      ];
```

3rd:

```
classwithtopic = [
    {
      classid: 1,
      subjectid: 10,
      topicid: 101,
      topicname: "topic 1 of id 10",
    },
    {
      classid: 1,
      subjectid: 11,
      topicid: 102,
      topicname: "topic 1 of id 11",
    },
    {
      classid: 2,
      subjectid: 11,
      topicid: 103,
      topicname: "topic 1 of id 11",
    },
    {
      classid: 2,
      subjectid: 11,
      topicid: 104,
      topicname: "topic 2 of id 11",
    },
    {
      classid: 2,
      subjectid: 11,
      topicid: 105,
      topicname: "topic 3 of id ",
    },
    {
      classid: 2,
      subjectid: 11,
      topicid: 106,
      topicname: "topic 4 of id 11",
    },
  ];
```

I need the final array to be like this,

```
finalarray = [
    {
      class_id: 1,
      class_name: "class1",
      subjects: [
        {
          subejct_id: 11,
          subejct_name: "English",
              topics: [{topicid:108,topicname: "topic 1 of id 11 "}, {topicid:107,topicname: "topic 2 of id 11 "}],
         {
          subejct_id: 10,
          subejct_name: "Hindi",
              topics: [{topicid:106,topicname: "topic 1 of id 10 "}, {topicid:107,topicname: "topic 2 of id 10 "}],
      ],
    },
    {
      class_id: 2,
      class_name: "class 2",
     subjects: [
        {
          subejct_id: 11,
          subejct_name: "English",
          topics: [{topicid:103,topicname: "topic 1 of id 11 "}, {topicid:104,topicname: "topic 2 of id 11 "}],
        },
         {
          subejct_id: 12,
          subejct_name: "Hindi",
          topics: [{topicid:100,topicname: "topic 1 of id 12 "}, {topicid:101,topicname: "topic 2 of id 12 "}],
        },
      ],
    },
    
  ];
```

I tried to use reduce but didn't succeed. I don't have any issue with time complexity of the code as i will handle that. Any help will be appreciated to achieve the final array.

Edit:

As asked by [@HereticMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) , i tried this on another array something like this.

```
selectedSubjects=[
{ subjectName: "maths", topicName: "topic1 of maths"}
{ subjectName: "maths", topicName: "topic2 of maths"}
{ subjectName: "English", topicName: "topic1 of English "}
{ subjectName: "English", topicName: "topic2 of English "}
]
```

On this array i applied this

```
const groups = this.selectedSubjects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      (acc[cur.subjectName] = acc[cur.subjectName] || []).push(cur.topicName);
      return acc;
    }, {}); // to group the array according to subject
    console.log(groups);

    this.array= Object.keys(groups).map((key) => ({
      SubjectName: key,
      topics: groups[key],
    }));
```

after this i got the result as:

```
array=[
{SubjectName: "maths"
topics:["topic1 of maths", "topic2 of maths "]
},
{SubjectName: "English"
topics:["topic1 of English", "topic2 of English"]
}
]
```

But I'm not getting how to apply this on three arrays.

Comment: great, where is your try?

Comment: Please show your attempt using `reduce`; you may be close and we can save time correcting your attempt rather than writing new code from whole cloth.

Comment: @HereticMonkey updated

Comment: @NinaScholz updated

Comment: Where is `test_2` coming from?  Do you really want your final array to remove classes with no subjects or whose subjects contain no topics?  Do you really want to use `subejct` instead of `subject` and `class_id` instead of `classId`?  Maybe you can clean up your example and elaborate on the requirements.

Comment: Oof, and you have multiple copies of `{classid: 1, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1"}` with different `topicname`s.  Oh and you don't seem to want `topicname` in your output array.  I'd really strongly suggest cleaning this up.

Comment: @jcalz updated the code. I dont have any condition for empty subject or topic . it can be left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a classig approach by mapping and filtering the wanted parts.

```js
const
    classes = [{ classid: 1, classname: "class 1" }, { classid: 2, classname: "class 2" }, { classid: 3, classname: "class 3" }, { classid: 4, classname: "class 4" }, { classid: 5, classname: "class 5" }],
    classwithSubjectIDSubjectName = [{ classid: 1, subjectid: 10, subjectname: "Hindi" }, { classid: 1, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" }, { classid: 3, subjectid: 12, subjectname: "GEO" }],
    classwithtopic = [{ classid: 1, subjectid: 10, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 1 of id 10" }, { classid: 1, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t3", topicname: "topic 1 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 1 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 2 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 3 of id " }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 4 of id 11" }],
    result = classes.map(({ classid: class_id, classname: class_name }) => ({
        class_id,
        class_name,
        subjects: classwithSubjectIDSubjectName
            .filter(q => q.classid === class_id)
            .map(({ subjectid: subject_id, subjectname: subject_name }) => ({
                subject_id,
                subject_name,
                topics: classwithtopic
                    .filter(q => q.classid === class_id && q.subjectid === subject_id)
                    .map(({ topicid: topic_id }) => ({
                        topic_id
                    }))
            }))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly faster approach by taking objects instad of filtering.

```js
const
    classes = [{ classid: 1, classname: "class 1" }, { classid: 2, classname: "class 2" }, { classid: 3, classname: "class 3" }, { classid: 4, classname: "class 4" }, { classid: 5, classname: "class 5" }],
    classwithSubjectIDSubjectName = [{ classid: 1, subjectid: 10, subjectname: "Hindi" }, { classid: 1, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, subjectname: "English" }, { classid: 3, subjectid: 12, subjectname: "GEO" }],
    classwithtopic = [{ classid: 1, subjectid: 10, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 1 of id 10" }, { classid: 1, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t3", topicname: "topic 1 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 1 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 2 of id 11" }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 3 of id " }, { classid: 2, subjectid: 11, topicid: "t1", topicname: "topic 4 of id 11" }],

    groupBy = (array, key) => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        const k = Array.isArray(key) ? key.map(k => o[k]).join('|') : o[key];
        (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    classSubject = groupBy(classwithSubjectIDSubjectName, 'classid'),
    classSubjectTopic = groupBy(classwithtopic, ['classid', 'subjectid']),

    result = classes.map(({ classid: class_id, classname: class_name }) => ({
        class_id,
        class_name,
        subjects: classSubject[class_id]?.map(({ subjectid: subject_id, subjectname: subject_name }) => ({
            subject_id,
            subject_name,
            topics: classSubjectTopic[[class_id, subject_id].join('|')]?.map(({ topicid: topic_id }) => ({
                topic_id
            }))
        }))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is a big issue, I'd just use a combination of `map()` and `filter()` to produce the final array, possibly like this:

```
const finalArray = classes.map(c => ({
    class_id: c.classid,
    class_name: c.classname,
    subjects: classwithSubjectIDSubjectName.filter(s => s.classid === c.classid).map(s => ({
        subejct_id: s.subjectid,
        subejct_name: s.subjectname,
        topics: classwithtopic.filter(t => t.classid === c.classid && t.subjectid === s.subjectid
        ).map(t => ({
            topicid: t.topicid,
            topicname: t.topicname
        }))
    }))
}))
```

which produces the following output:

```
[
  {
    "class_id": 1,
    "class_name": "class 1",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "subejct_id": 10,
        "subejct_name": "Hindi",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicid": "t1",
            "topicname": "topic 1 of id 10"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "subejct_id": 11,
        "subejct_name": "English",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicid": "t3",
            "topicname": "topic 1 of id 11"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "class_id": 2,
    "class_name": "class 2",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "subejct_id": 11,
        "subejct_name": "English",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicid": "t1",
            "topicname": "topic 1 of id 11"
          },
          {
            "topicid": "t1",
            "topicname": "topic 2 of id 11"
          },
          {
            "topicid": "t1",
            "topicname": "topic 3 of id "
          },
          {
            "topicid": "t1",
            "topicname": "topic 4 of id 11"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "class_id": 3,
    "class_name": "class 3",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "subejct_id": 12,
        "subejct_name": "GEO",
        "topics": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "class_id": 4,
    "class_name": "class 4",
    "subjects": []
  },
  {
    "class_id": 5,
    "class_name": "class 5",
    "subjects": []
  }
]
```

It's hard for me to tell if this is *exactly* what you want, since your example result is inconsistent with your example inputs, but hopefully this should be enough to get you moving.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMA2BDCECmEYF4YG0CwAUDMTAN5xIoCWAJgFwwCMANBchGIgLaoMBECdkz4wAvs0IkybavRgAmVoJSce-ZRnkjxkkuQ20GAZiWUO3XjAFmYR7RKJ6ZEQzAAsp9qsvWhb+7rE+mauAKyeKhbqNqEBBAC6ANyEhKCQsBoA7lRQABYAygCuAEYAVqjAUACSACJFZRVQAHIWWLiB0gZyLDAQJeWVrowADKx9DZXe-AASVGA0VHFSwexDY-2NQz3jA1BTVgCiYADm8FQQuUtOXQyKvRuD3dsPe1GHJ2cXV0HOrib3EygQzuO0a+z4AHEDgB5OJJFIENLQZzZPJQEAAByowDa+EcQQ6UhuTAcUikoMeDBGpLJxHRWOArj4UEYfBptPp2PBnJxjBgIAAZjBaExhmyOjp8WRCSRiSwZcQKUCnuyyTymVA7KqpDzuZjsUx+UKRYxWarJcsFb85IorUqttqSOq5MyzVbdW9mfreUbhTQmG6pRa9FbibapeSXg73d6NYHaXTvXqGQpfSb4yRgwSI7KQjbHYqoyqYwy4+Kc4mGcmDUY0-7y1Is9KK9bbgWAbtoy3nfwWQ2Ex61FYee46wH+8RJfCCKlwMiBXNEPAAIIAJ1XiAAnm0NOgAHRcRAYgAUOMwAD4YMfSB0NAB9VzAPddVX3-ZPjTeVVKiAMLI5AoXlqepdhaHg9wXeAoFQVdjwwC9emfPMsEwbAPzzABKA8jzgrBL2vO0SlQUpKgfOQID3e0aHbcZiNI-YKKVL8S2xX8UQAnkIKoKCYOPWAEKgJDVn9VC0KE2QYAAMkkmBBKolDsEYosrSww8T34-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-qlOObad9h1o8FO4vDzL-HhwEfaToGM5SrHwiLl26sy2Jc+93Kk8IH6wpCoA)

Comment: thanks , this answer was also very helpful but i got the right answer above.appreciate your efforts.